# pandas to_csv , number of unique record reduces

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a pandas dataframe to a csv file. However I can find that number of unique ids are decreasing, but total number of rows remains the same

Below you can find the code:

checking total count and unique count of grouped_test

```
 grouped_test['fullVisitorId'].nunique() , grouped_test['fullVisitorId'].count() 
(639230, 639230)
```

Submitting to a csv file

```
grouped_test.to_csv('result.csv',index=False)
```

Reading the same csv file again

```
result = pd.read_csv('result.csv')
```

I got below warning when reading the file

```
py:2785: DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

checking the count

```
result['fullVisitorId'].nunique() , result['fullVisitorId'].count()
(638932, 639230)
```

You can find the number of unique id decreases, any idea what could be the issue.

Below you can find some sample values of Ids. Does the length/datatype of the id has anything to do with it?

```
9844437513179813866
643697640977915618
```

Comment: Try  the below before saving to csv
Try grouped_test['fullVisitorId'] = grouped_test['fullVisitorId'].astype(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, your guess that length of integers matters is right.

Let's do some experiments with data to prove that.

**Experiment 1**

Let's see what is the biggest integer Pandas can handle:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[9223372036854775899]})
df.to_csv("try.csv", index=False)
df1 = pd.read_csv("try.csv", dtype={"a":int})
df1

a
0   9223372036854775899


df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[92233720368547758100]})
df.to_csv("try.csv", index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv("try.csv", dtype={"a":int})
df2

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._try_int64()

OverflowError: Overflow
```

So, the question now how should we *properly* specify format of the numbers

**Experiment 2**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[98444375131798787989138668, 98444375131798787989138669]})
df.to_csv("try.csv", index=False)
df3 = pd.read_csv("try.csv", dtype={"a":float})

df3.a.nunique()

1
```

We see that `float` is *eating* numbers

**Experiment 3**

Let's try `object` format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[98444375131798787989138668, 98444375131798787989138669]})
df.to_csv("try.csv", index=False)
df4 = pd.read_csv("try.csv", dtype={"a":object})

df4.a.nunique()

2
```

In short, the answer to your question is to specify the data type on reading as `object`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("result.csv", dtype={"fullVisitorId":object})
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to rule out any data type issues would be by enforcing the datatype as integer (before saving to csv as well as immediately reading from the csv.

Upon reading:

```
result = pd.read_csv('result.csv')
result['fullVisitorId'] = result['fullVisitorId'].astype(int)
result['fullVisitorId'].nunique() , result['fullVisitorId'].count()
```

There is also in infer_objects() which you may want to explore